# Section Header styles

Tags: header-footer, packages, titlesec, cv, resume

I was updating my Resume and came across this header can anyone share the code to create this :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you like the answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basing only on the information you provided, I'd say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\textsc{Academic Achievements}\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image: strong text]

Comment: Thanks, @Alessandro Cuttin